# SSMS connects the database instantly while the SqlClient in C# takes a minute?

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, ado.net, .net-core-3.0

In the .Net Core 3.0 console application (`System.Data.SqlClient`), I had to add `Connect Timeout` to prevent the timeout exception.

```
using var conn = new SqlConnection($"Server={server};Database={db};Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Connect Timeout=60");
conn.Open(); // Waiting....
```

However, it connects instantly in Sql Server management studio (on the same PC)? What can be the slowness reason?

Comment: Please check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/media/sql-database-connect-query-ssms/options-connect-to-db.png Connection Properties/Additional parameters Maybe there is something different

Comment: Are you running your test on the same box as SSMS?   From that box, what does `nslookup MyServer' output?  Exactly what NuGet package are you using for SqlClient?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, it's a .Net Core 3.0 console application (`System.Data.SqlClient`). `nslookup myserver` outputs `Server: a-ns02.mydomain.net/Address: 168.40.0.1/Name: myserver.ad.mydomain.net/Addresses: 10.120.x.x/10.140.y.y`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nslookup myserver
```

outputs

```
Server: a-ns02.mydomain.net
Address: 168.40.0.1

Name: myserver.ad.mydomain.net
Addresses: 10.120.x.x
           10.140.y.y
```

Looks like this is a Multi-Subnet AG Listener, right?  If so try adding `MultiSubnetFailover=true` in the connection string.

This doesn't happen any more on .NET Framework, since  `TransparentNetworkIPResolution` was implemented in .NET Framework 4.6.1.  And SSMS uses the .NET Framework version of SqlClient.

But this enhancement is not yet in .NET Core (tracking [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/99)).  Until it's fixed you'll have to explicitly set MultiSubnetFailover=true to avoid these timeouts.  (Or disable [RegisterAllProviderIP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/create-or-configure-an-availability-group-listener-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) on the Client Access Point in the cluster if, for some reason, you can't change the connection string).

Comment: `MultiSubnetFailover=true` resolved the problem. I didn't try `TransparentNetworkIPResolution`

Comment: Coll, can you give it a try and let me knot?  TransparentNetworkIPResolution is supposed to be on by default and mitigate this issue, even without MultiSubnetFailover=true.  So there may a buggable issue here.

Comment: Do you mean try `TransparentNetworkIPResolution=true` alone? It's very fast since added `MultiSubnetFailover=true`

Comment: Yes. `MultiSubnetFailover=true` is the best setting, but `TransparentNetworkIPResolution` is supposed to be on by default, and to reduce the delay to a second or two, avoiding the timeouts.

Comment: It gets error of `System.ArgumentException: 'Keyword not supported: 'transparentnetworkipresolution'.'`

Comment: See update.  TransparentNetworkIPResolution isn't in .NET Core yet.